# Remote visualvm to server in weblogic cluster

Tags: weblogic

I have weblogic appserver version 10.3, installed on linux . I created 3 server name: s1,s2,s3 run on cluster.
I can connect remote from visualvm  to adminserver with config in startWebLogic.sh as:
 JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}    -Duser.timezone=GMT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4444 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=FALSE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=FALSE -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.2 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"

However, i can not do that with s1, s2, s3 though i used difference port for every server.

please help me ! how can i do ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to profile weblogic's managed servers you'll need to add the jmxremote settings to `startManagedWebLogic.sh` or through the admin console (as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/startstop/ConfigureStartupArgumentsForManagedServers.html)). 
I'd also double check the IP address and make sure it's the correct one for each of your 3 servers.